# Frequency out of range ATI HD 4670

Tags: 11.10, boot, ati, frequency

Today, I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my desktop computer. I have never used linux before, so I am completely new to it. It started out quite well, and I like it quite much right now.

Though, I cannot install drivers to my graphic card. My graphic card is Sapphire HD Radeon 4670, and whenever I install drivers with the Hardware drivers application, or install drivers from ati.com, I get "frequency out of range" as soon as I reboot the computer.

That's why I have reinstalled ubuntu like 4 times today. I am sick of it, and now I want a real solution. Have you guys got any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think "windows" with Linux. If the open source driver is working, stick with it. If you can login to your desktop without doing anything special like choosing unity 2d, then everything is up and running. You seldom have to install any special drivers in Linux, it's all built into system. Proprietary drivers from Ati tends to give headache.

Comment: So, does that mean that I can play games like WC3 without any drivers, just a plain installation of Ubuntu 11.10? On Windows XP, my computer can play MW2 on medium/high graphics. I want the best performance available for my Ubuntu computer, even though I probably won't play any games except Warcraft 3. Feels like a waste to have poor performance while I could get better. Cheers.

Comment: Well, you DO have drivers, they are just not atis own, and they work much better in your daily work. But if games are your thing then the Atidriver is better. I have a hd4850 myself and I have never been able to use the fglrxdriver. Systemcrashes all the time... Try with open drivers first, if they perform well enough, stick with that.

Comment: Alright, but do you experience any lag or something like that in 720-1080HD on Youtube? For me, it doesn't really feel so smooth. It's watchable, but I can see that it's a bit choppy. Also, the maximum resolution I can have is 1024x768, the other resolution available is 800x600, nothing else.

Comment: Hmm, I installed Ubuntu 10.04 and the problem seems to be solved, also, I like the GUI in Ubuntu more. I will stick to it until I see a fix or something similar to that. Cheers.

Comment: I did the same. Has to do with r600g drivers which are the ones we are using with our cards. They are not quite ready yet. Hopefully they work better with the next lts-release. Good luck in the Linuxworld!